How do I correctly extract my intended values using str_extract_all?
I have the following toy dataframe:
df <- data.frame(
  product = c("apple", "banana", "cherry", "durian", "eggplant", "fuyu"),
  ingredients = c("flour|fibre|500", "sugar|500", "505|wheat|flavouring", "fibre(500)|eggs", "wholegrainrice|sesameoil", "500|fibre|500"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

My aim is to detect whether fibre appears in a product's ingredients, count how many times it appears and extract the values used to record fibre in a product's ingredients.
For the purposes of this analysis, fibre can be represented in a product's ingredients as "fibre", "500" or "fibre(500)".
My current code is:
library(tidyverse)

fibre_strings_to_check <- c("fibre", "500", "fibre\\(500\\)")

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    fibre_present = str_detect(ingredients, paste(fibre_strings_to_check, collapse = "|")),
    fibre_count = str_count(ingredients, paste(fibre_strings_to_check, collapse = "|")),
    fibre_used = str_extract_all(ingredients, paste(fibre_strings_to_check, collapse = "|"))
  )

Which gives the output of df2 as:
| product  | ingredients                 | fibre_present | fibre_count | fibre_used        |
|----------|-----------------------------|---------------|-------------|-------------------|
| apple    | flour\|fibre\|500           | TRUE          | 2           | fibre, 500        |
| banana   | sugar\|500                  | TRUE          | 1           | 500               |
| cherry   | 505\|wheat\|flavouring      | FALSE         | 0           |                   |
| durian   | fibre(500)\|eggs            | TRUE          | 2           | fibre, 500        |
| eggplant | wholegrainrice\|sesameoil   | FALSE         | 0           |                   |
| fuyu     | 500\|fibre\|500             | TRUE          | 3           | 500, fibre, 500   |


The issue I am having is with the "durian" product. I want "fibre(500)" to be counted as one value / instance of fibre as it has been defined in fibre_strings_to_check. But because it seems to match the other instances of fibre in fibre_strings_to_check, it's counting as two values / instances of fibre.
My intended output of df2 is:
| product  | ingredients                 | fibre_present | fibre_count | fibre_used        |
|----------|-----------------------------|---------------|-------------|-------------------|
| apple    | flour\|fibre\|500           | TRUE          | 2           | fibre, 500        |
| banana   | sugar\|500                  | TRUE          | 1           | 500               |
| cherry   | 505\|wheat\|flavouring      | FALSE         | 0           |                   |
| durian   | fibre(500)\|eggs            | TRUE          | 1           | fibre(500)        |
| eggplant | wholegrainrice\|sesameoil   | FALSE         | 0           |                   |
| fuyu     | 500\|fibre\|500             | TRUE          | 3           | 500, fibre, 500   |

How do I adjust the script so that there is no double counting of what is intended to be a single value?

A quick fix would be to rearrange the vector fibre_strings_to_check  so that "fibre\\(500\\)" occurs first than rest of the values.
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

fibre_strings_to_check <- c("fibre\\(500\\)", "fibre", "500")
fibre_regex <- paste(fibre_strings_to_check, collapse = "|")

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    fibre_present = str_detect(ingredients, fibre_regex),
    fibre_count = str_count(ingredients, fibre_regex),
    fibre_used = str_extract_all(ingredients, fibre_regex)
  )

df2
#   product              ingredients fibre_present fibre_count      fibre_used
#1    apple          flour|fibre|500          TRUE           2      fibre, 500
#2   banana                sugar|500          TRUE           1             500
#3   cherry     505|wheat|flavouring         FALSE           0                
#4   durian          fibre(500)|eggs          TRUE           1      fibre(500)
#5 eggplant wholegrainrice|sesameoil         FALSE           0                
#6     fuyu            500|fibre|500          TRUE           3 500, fibre, 500


I really like regex, but here's a list take. It may be easier to adjust for others ingredients.
df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(
    unique_ingredients = str_split(ingredients, pattern = "\\|"),
    fibre_ingredients  = map(unique_ingredients, \(x) keep(x, \(y) y %in% fibre_strings_to_check)),
    
    fibre_present = map_lgl(fibre_ingredients, \(x) some(x, \(y) y %in% fibre_strings_to_check)),
    fibre_count   = map_int(fibre_ingredients, length),
    fibre_used    = map_chr(fibre_ingredients, str_flatten_comma))

Output:
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  product  ingredients              unique_ingredients fibre_ingredients fibre_present fibre_count fibre_used       
  <chr>    <chr>                    <list>             <list>            <lgl>               <int> <chr>            
1 apple    flour|fibre|500          <chr [3]>          <chr [2]>         TRUE                    2 "fibre, 500"     
2 banana   sugar|500                <chr [2]>          <chr [1]>         TRUE                    1 "500"            
3 cherry   505|wheat|flavouring     <chr [3]>          <chr [0]>         FALSE                   0 ""               
4 durian   fibre(500)|eggs          <chr [2]>          <chr [1]>         TRUE                    1 "fibre(500)"     
5 eggplant wholegrainrice|sesameoil <chr [2]>          <chr [0]>         FALSE                   0 ""               
6 fuyu     500|fibre|500            <chr [3]>          <chr [3]>         TRUE                    3 "500, fibre, 500"

